# 301 correct way to redirect a directory

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I was wondering what would be the correct way to do a redirect like this:

```
Redirect 301 /about/$ http://domain.com/new-about/
Redirect 301 /about$ http://domain.com/new-about/
Redirect 301 /about/me http://domain.com/new-about/
```

That's how I currently do it and it works but I believe there should be a better way?

I have 2 pages which are rewrited, one page is a subpage of the other page `/about/me/`, now both pages should redirect to the new page `new-about`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should either use [RedirectMatch](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch) or use mod_rewrite to perform regular expression matching. This should work and would be the shortest and best performing solution:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/about /new-about/
```

Domain and protocol are optional - leaving them out like this will keep them as they were, so this is future proof.

Answer (score 0):

Been a while since I asked this question and I am now more comfortable with regular expressions.

The way I would do this now is:

```
Redirect 301 ^/about http://domain.com/new-about/
```

A tool which helped me a lot understanding regular expressions and which I would advice anyone trying to understand them is Rubular: http://rubular.com/

Comment: It doesn't?! My whole life was a lie :(